# Dnn Installation,Unable to connect to database. installWizard.aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, installation, database-connection, dotnetnuke

I am installing donnetnukes.
below errors is showing.

"No valid default database connection detected. Standard Database setup option is unavailable"

ERROR: DotNetNuke requires SQL 2008 (express or full product) to work.

screenshot:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bODakjneIYg/UiMEjieEGxI/AAAAAAAAA4U/HkN5Wq_oZyk/w620-h553-no/Untitled-3.png

Answer (score 3):

The error is not as straight forward as you may think, Chris. If you're sure you have at least SQL Express 2008 or later installed, ensure 3 other things.

Go to your Sql Sever Config Manager and

1. Ensure SQL Server 2005 is uninstalled
2. Ensure that SQL Server Browser is running.
3. Ensure that under SQL Sever Network Configuartion --> Protocols both Named Pipes and TCP/IP is enabled.

If you have trouble enabling SQL Server browser, first stop the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) services, right click on the SQL Server Browser --> Properties --> Services Tab --> Start Mode set to "Automatic". Then you can restart both services. This will not work if you do not stop the SQLEXPRESS Server. At least it did not for me. :)

Comment: Hi, I do have the same error, I tried the same solution of you. But still not working.

Answer (score 1):

That error is straightforward, you either need to install SQL Express, using the defaults (not a named instance), or you need to provide the IP address, database name, and user connection info for the SQL server you are using.

Comment: Hi Chris, i tried database type as SQL Server, Server Name as "localhost" and also "." and provided the server credentials and still it throws the same error, no valid database connection detected. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that got me - I installed on Windows Server 2012 and the site wasn't trusted in Internet Explorer.

There must be some client scripts that need to run at start-up which are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem. If use the custom option and then **active the SA user and password in your SQL server**, you will be able to continue the process.

The reason is that this wizard gets the IIS pool user as a default one. Hence, if you create a user, you will be able to connect to that specific user & password without any problem.

I hope you find this text helpful.